# Geometric transformation using MATLAB Function block

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, simulink, matlab-cvst

I tried to apply a geometric transformation to a video using MATLAB Function block in Simulink. I connected a 'From Multimedia File' block to MATLAB Function block ant its output to a 'To Video Display' block. Inside MATLAB Function Block this code:

```
function outputImage = fcn(inputImage,theta)


coder.extrinsic('affine2d')
coder.extrinsic('imwarp')
outputImage = coder.nullcopy(inputImage);


tform = affine2d([cosd(theta) -sind(theta) 0; sind(theta) cosd(theta) 0; 0 0 1]);

outputImage = imwarp(inputImage,tform);
```

where angle theta is a constant block of 10. The code above is an example from 'affine2d' function examples. It returns me following error:

```
Size mismatch for MATLAB expression 'imwarp'. Expected = 120x160x3 Actual = 146x179x3 Block MATLAB Function (#108) While executing: State During Action
```

but I don't understand where is the error (why Actual=146x179x3). The input video is a RGB video file ('vipmen.avi') from CV toolbox demos.

**EDIT:** I solved it: I used `Apply Geometric Transformation` block for translation and a `Rotate` block for rotation with:

```
H = [1 0; 0 1; Ox-X  Oy-Y] %where Ox,Oy are image framework origin coordinates and X,Y are offset coordinates.
```

Indeed after translation, the "new" image framework origin is the (X,Y) point and the `Rotate` block rotates it about (X,Y).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Computer Vision System Toolbox includes a block called [Apply Geometric Transformation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/applygeometrictransformation.html), which will do what you need and save you the trouble of using MATLAB function block.

**Edit:**
The Apply Geometric Transformation block has been deprecated as of R2015b release. Please use the [Warp](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/warp.html) block instead.

Comment: I tried to use it but it have not notation: R = [cosd(theta) -sind(theta) 0; sind(theta) cosd(theta) 0; 0 0 1]; it have H = [h1 h4; h2 h5; h3 h6]; so I can transform input image frame origin and not a point defined in image-frame coordinates. Hope I was clear

Comment: That notation is exactly what you need.  h1 = cosd(theta). h2 = sind(theta). h3 = 0. h4 = -sind(theta). h5 = cosd(theta). h6 = 0.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the projective transformation, and use your R matrix as is.

Comment: I have to do a complete transformation as rotation and translation but 'affine' form want, for example, x_hat = x*h1 + y*h2 + h3 where if I have to do a translation I can replace h3,h6 with Ox-X,Oy-Y where Ox,Oy is image frame origin and X,Y is translation offset. But, now I have to do a rotation-translation, if I replace h1=cos(th), h2 = sind(theta), h3 = Ox-X, it performs a correct translation but rotation is about frame origin and not about (X,Y) point.

Comment: And if I don't have R2015b release? A method to solve it differently? What I exactly need is how to create a tform object before `tform = affine2d([cosd(theta) -sind(theta) 0; sind(theta) cosd(theta) 0; 0 0 1]);` It returns an error: _Maximum recursion limit of 500 reached. Use set(0,'RecursionLimit',N) to change the limit. Be aware that exceeding your available stack space can crash MATLAB and/or your computer._

Comment: @SPS, sorry, not clear what you are asking. If you are using Simulink, then use the Apply Geometric Transform block. If you are using matlab, then your code for constructing an `affine2d` object should work. There is nothing to do before that. My guess is that your recursion error is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: @Dima, sorry, my code is this: `function outputImage=fcn(inputImage,theta)
coder.extrinsic('affine2d');
coder.extrinsic('imwarp');
outputImage = coder.nullcopy(inputImage);
tform = projective2d([cosd(theta) -sind(theta) 0; sind(theta) cosd(theta) 0; 0 0 1]);
outputImage = imwarp(inputImage,tform);` At the _tform_ line, it return: _Maximum recursion limit of 500 reached. Use set(0,'RecursionLimit',N) to change the limit_ So the issue is I'm using **projective2d** function and not **affine2d**. I think I need to allocate memory for the tform object, or what?? Thanks

Comment: @SPS, so are you in matlab or simulink? In simulink, since you are only doing rotation, you should use the Rotate block. http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/rotate.html

Comment: @Dima, the code showed is just a rotation (it comes from the code above as example), but usually I have a full deformation, so I need **projective2d**. I'm in simulink, but I don't have the block **projective2d** and I'd like to do by myself. That's why I'm here. Any suggestion?

Comment: For one, you have `affine2d` in the `coder.extrinsic` statement, and then you are using `projective2d`. Also, what version of matlab are you using? Do you have the Computer Vision System Toolbox?

Comment: @Dima, I used a MATLAB function block in Simulink, which code is the following `function Output = distortion(X,DEF)
coder.extrinsic('imwarp');
coder.extrinsic('projective2d'); 
Output=coder.nullcopy(X);
tform=projective2d(DEF);
Output=imwarp(X,tform);` So this block has an image and a 3x3 matrix as input and an image as output. This block should operate on each image of a video stream.

Comment: The problem is that it returns an error: _Maximum recursion limit of 500 reached. Use set(0,'RecursionLimit',N) to change the limit. Be aware that exceeding your available stack space can crash MATLAB and/or your computer._ from tform line

Comment: If you tell me which version of matlab you have, I can try reproducing it.

Comment: I think i solved. `tform` called another file in the workspace called tform.m. I changed the name and I'm going on.

Comment: At the end I got the same problem of above:  _Size mismatch for MATLAB expression 'imwarp'. Expected = 1280x720x3 Actual = 991x1152x3 Block MATLAB Function (#31) While executing: none_  The input video/image is 1280x720 in this case. I don't have R2015b but only R2013a. How to solve?

Comment: @Dima, do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

As an image is warped/rotated the number of rows and/or columns in it will change.

You'll need to modify your code so that outputImage is variable sized.
To do this open the code (for the MATLAB Function Block) in the editor and open up the "Edit Data" dialog.
Select outputImage in the left hand column, then

1. check the "variable size" check box
2. enter something like [400 400 3] as the size

You have to make a best guess for the maximum row and column size that you expect.

Note also that the Matlab function block must have a discrete sample time for it to use variable sized signals.
To set this, right click on the block and select Block Parameters, then set a sample time.

Comment: why [400 400 3] ? It is 2 times diagonal.

Comment: 400 was "randomly" chosen as I knew it was going to be plenty big enough.  You most likely want it to equal to the length of the diagonal (with zero rotation), but should test different values.

Comment: How to do this _open the code (for the MATLAB Function Block) in the editor and open up the "Edit Data" dialog_? Where is the **Edit Data**? There is not with right click on the MATLAB Function block, neither in the Edit menu of Simulink model

Comment: Open the code for the block by double-clicking the block.  Select the "Editor" tab across the top of the Editor, and on the ribbon (near the right hand end) there is an "Edit Data" button.

Comment: @PhilGoddard, I got it. My MATLAB Function block gets as input an image of 720x1280px and outputs an image of 401x601px (that is 601x401 as matrix). So I set in the 'Edit Data': for the input _Scope: Input, Size: [1280 720 3], checked Variable size, empty for the Limit range_  and for the output _Scope: Output, Size: [650 720 3], checked Variable size, empty for the Limit range_ But it returns: _Size computation for img (#32) failed. The size definition did not evaluate
to a positive integer value._ What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved trying to understand what happens. The deformed image has a dimension different from `Output=coder.nullcopy(X)` so I calculated the dimension of the new deformed image, create a blank image with `Output=coder.nullcopy(ones(new_row,new_colomn,3))` and that works